# Where is the value when I do this in pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have the following code.

```
s2 = pd.Series([100,"PYTHON","Soochow","Qiwsir"],
               index=["mark","title","university","name"])

s2.mark = "102"

s2.price = "100"
```

When I print `s2` , I can see the value of mark was changed  and there is no price; but I can get result by printing `s2.price`. Why is the `price` not printed?

Comment: Meta: [Why is this a bad question-?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365834/why-is-this-a-bad-question) - consensus is, it's not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are confusing attributes with series indices.

The syntax `s2.xyz = 100` first looks for `xyz` in the series *index* and overwrites it if it exists.

If it does not exist, it adds a new *attribute* to the series.

**How to add an attribute**

```
if 'price' not in s2:
    s2.price = 100
```

You should not add attributes which conflict with indices; this is asking for trouble given the similar syntax permitted for access.

**How to add an element to series**

In order to *add* an element to the series with an index, use `pd.Series.loc`:

```
s2.loc['price'] = 100
```

**How to tell the difference**

Run `s2.__dict__`. You will find:

```
{'_data': SingleBlockManager
 Items: Index(['mark', 'title', 'university', 'name'], dtype='object')
 ObjectBlock: 4 dtype: object,
 '_index': Index(['mark', 'title', 'university', 'name'], dtype='object'),
 '_item_cache': {},
 '_name': None,
 '_subtyp': 'series',
 'is_copy': None,
 'price': '100'}
```

It is clear that `price` has been added as an *attribute*, not as an *index*.