# How to create a time attribute?

Tags: python

I have the following dataset :

```
SessionNo ItemNo  TransactType
1           12        0
1           13        1    
1           12        1
2           15        0
...
```

I want to generate a new attribute `Time` according to
the `SessionNo` attribute. The new dataset looks like that :

```
SessionNo  Time  ItemNo  TransactType
    1        1    12        0
    1        2    13        1    
    1        3    12        1
    2        1    15        0
   ...
```

Is there a simple way to perform this task in Python?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you had another Session 1 after the 2, would you have Time=4, or would it reset to 1?

Comment: For the moment, I have no idea, how to perform this. SessionNo is a kind of "Id" and is always increasing, so after SessionNo = 2, SessionNo = 1 is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

You will have to add 1 to the result to start the count at 1 instead of 0:

```
In [18]: df['Time'] = df.groupby('SessionNo').cumcount()+1

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
   SessionNo  ItemNo  TransactType  Time
0          1      12             0     1
1          1      13             1     2
2          1      12             1     3
3          2      15             0     1
```

Comment: @Krukiou, Note: *attribute* is a term which has an [entirely different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748749/where-is-the-value-when-i-do-this-in-pandas-series) meaning to *series*, even in the context of `pandas`. Here we assume, as per your desired output, that you want a new series.

Comment: Thanks for the answer : I didn't know the cumcount() function.