# Attach data source info to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, metadata, series

Is there a way to attach information on the data source to a pandas series? At the moment I just add columns to the dataframe that indicate the source for each variable...

Thanks a lot for ideas and suggestions!

Comment: Will there be one source for the whole series, or a different source for each row/label?

Comment: It will be the same for the whole series..

Comment: [Adding meta information to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14688306/adding-meta-information-metadata-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the offical [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#define-original-properties):

> To let original data structures have additional properties, you should
>   let `pandas` know what properties are added. `pandas` maps unknown
>   properties to data names overriding `__getattribute__`. Defining
>   original properties can be done in one of 2 ways:
>
> 1. Define `_internal_names` and `_internal_names_set` for temporary properties which WILL NOT be passed to manipulation results.
> 2. Define `_metadata` for normal properties which will be passed to manipulation results.
>
> Below is an example to define two original properties,
>   “internal_cache” as a temporary property and “added_property” as a
>   normal property
>
> ```
> class SubclassedDataFrame2(DataFrame):
>
>     # temporary properties
>     _internal_names = pd.DataFrame._internal_names + ['internal_cache']
>     _internal_names_set = set(_internal_names)
>
>     # normal properties
>     _metadata = ['added_property']
>
> @property
> def _constructor(self):
>     return SubclassedDataFrame2
> ```
>
> _
>
> ```
> >>> df = SubclassedDataFrame2({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
> >>> df
>    A  B  C
> 0  1  4  7
> 1  2  5  8
> 2  3  6  9
>
> >>> df.internal_cache = 'cached'
> >>> df.added_property = 'property'
>
> >>> df.internal_cache
> cached
> >>> df.added_property
> property
>
> # properties defined in _internal_names is reset after manipulation
> >>> df[['A', 'B']].internal_cache
> AttributeError: 'SubclassedDataFrame2' object has no attribute 'internal_cache'
>
> # properties defined in _metadata are retained
> >>> df[['A', 'B']].added_property
> property
> ```

As you can see the benefit of defining custom properties through `_metadata` is that the properties will be propagated automatically during (most) one-to-one dataframe operations. Be aware though that during many-to-one dataframe operations (e.g. `merge()` or `concat()`) your custom properties will still be lost.

Comment: IIUC this adds properties to a `DataFrame`, not to its `Series` objects...

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter A `Series` object that is created from a `DataFrame` (e.g. by slicing) will indeed not inherit the dataframe's metadata properties. See also [pandas github issue #19850](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19850).

Comment: Sure, but then it doesn't answer the (and my) question.

Answer (score 2):

Like most Python objects, you can add an attribute using period (`.`) syntax. However, you should be careful your attribute names do not conflict with labels. Here's a demonstration:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(list(range(3)), index=list('abc'))
s.a = 10
s.d = 20

print(s.a, s.d)

10 20

print(s)

a    10
b     1
c     2
```

As above you may unwittingly overwrite the value for a label when in fact you want to add an `a` attribute. One way to alleviate this problem, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748881/9209546), is to perform a simple check:

```
if 'a' not in s:
    s.a = 100
else:
    print('Attempt to overwrite label when setting attribute aborted!')
    # or raise a custom error
```

Note that operations on a dataframe such as `GroupBy`, `pivot`, etc, as described [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2485), may return copies of data with attributes removed.

Finally, for *storing* dataframes or series with meta data attached, you may wish to consider HDF5. See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49740190/saving-in-a-file-an-array-or-dataframe-together-with-other-information/49991172#49991172).